# Reconnecting TCPClient throws exception

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sockets, tcp

Im connecting to a Socket Server to send and receive messages. Everything works fine as messages are coming in and out but every once in a while it loses connection. Im trying to catch the exception and reconnect to the server. 
The first exception when it loses connection:

System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)

and then when it tries to reconnect:

System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)

My question is what am I doing wrong? And what is the best solution to reconnect to the server?
My code looks something like this:

```
  class Test
        {
            private TcpClient myTcpClient;
            private NetworkStream myStream;
            private string host = xxx.xxx.xxx;
            private int port = 8888;
            private string streaming = "";

        public void Listen()
        {
            this.myTcpClient = new TcpClient(host, port);
            this.myStream = this.myTcpClient.GetStream();
            Listener();
        }

        private void Listener()
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    byte[] numResponse = new byte[8192];
                    int x = this.myStream.Read(numResponse, 0, numResponse.Length);
                    Decrypt(numResponse, 0, x);
                    string stream = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(numResponse);
                    this.streaming = string.Concat(this.streaming, stream);
                }
            }
            catch(Excpetion ex)
            {
                // write ex.ToString() to TextFile
                this.myTcpClient = new TcpClient(host, port);
                this.myStream = this.myTcpClient.GetStream();
                Listener();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unrelated, but you're not using the return value from myStream.Read. This is always a bug. Use a StreamReader to read from a NetworkStream. Your Unicode decoding is also broken because packets might be split arbitrarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your exception is being caused because you are doing the re-init inside the catch statement.

While inside the catch the network stream is still open. So when you create a new TCP client with the same port, I'm guessing it is using the same network stream as before, which is locked trying to read.

Inside the catch, you could try

```
 this.myTcpClient.Close();
 this.myTcpClient.Dispose();
 this.myTcpClient = new TcpClient(host, port);
 this.myStream = this.myTcpClient.GetStream();
```

That might work. But I'd recommend not doing that in the catch since you might cause another exception. I'd say try read up on some examples as well since this code does have other problems as mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You should not read in while(true) loop.  Better check if myStream.Read return 0 bytes or TCP related exception happens, in this case connection will be closed I think, you need to dispose the resources and reconnect again.

Here you can find safe reading method - http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/readbinary.html

Answer (score -1):

Here is some code which might help

```
// State object for receiving data from remote device.
public class StateObject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Client socket.
    /// </summary>
    public Socket workSocket = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Size of receive buffer.
    /// </summary>
    public const int BufferSize = 256;

    /// <summary>
    /// Receive buffer.
    /// </summary>
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];

    /// <summary>
    /// Received data string.
    /// </summary>
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}

public class AsynchronousClient
{
    // The port number for the remote device.
    private const int _port = xxxx;
    private const string _address = "xx.xx.xx.xx";

    // ManualResetEvent instances signal completion.
    private static ManualResetEvent _connectDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent _sendDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent _receiveDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    private static string _response = string.Empty;

    public static void StartClient(string data)
    {
        // Connect to a remote device.
        try
        {
            var client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Connect to the remote endpoint.
            client.BeginConnect(_address, _port, ConnectCallback, client);
            _connectDone.WaitOne();

            // Send test data to the remote device.
            //Console.WriteLine("Sending data : {0}", data);
            Send(client, "US\r\n");
            _sendDone.WaitOne();


            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Send(client, data);
            _sendDone.WaitOne();


            // Receive the response from the remote device.                
            Receive(client);
            _receiveDone.WaitOne();

            // Write the response to the console.
            //Console.WriteLine("Response received : {0}", _response);

            // Release the socket.
            client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            client.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            var client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete the connection.
            client.EndConnect(ar);

            Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}", client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

            // Signal that the connection has been made.
            _connectDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void Receive(Socket client)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create the state object.
            var state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = client;

            // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, ReceiveCallback, state);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the state object and the client socket 
            // from the asynchronous state object.
            var state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            var client = state.workSocket;

            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, ReceiveCallback, state);
            }
            else
            {
                // All the data has arrived; put it in response.
                if (state.sb.Length > 1) _response = state.sb.ToString();                    
                _receiveDone.Set();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void Send(Socket client, String data)
    {            
        var byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0, SendCallback, client);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            var client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            var bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);                
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);                
            _sendDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this code is socket based, while author tries to use TcpClient.

Comment: same..isn't tcpclient just a wrapper over sockets?

Comment: it's a wrapper.  But author tries to figure out a problem in his code and not asking for new solution

Comment: also code you've provided doesn't handle reconnect and closes connection after receive